# JSON not loading with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: json, jquery

I am using a web service that returns JSON data.

test.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords

Loading this URL in a browser prompts me to open incident.do, which opened in Notepad displays the valid JSON data.

Then, in a web page in the same domain, I use this:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authinfo);        
},
   url: "https://test.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(a,b,c) {
     alert(a);
   }
 });
```

However, with this code I am not receiving any JSON, I get only this response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Jul 2010 22:28:09 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: If it helps anyone, I have a link to the sandbox on the provider's website that provides the same functionality...The username/password is admin/admin

https://demo.service-now.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords

Comment: is the Content-Type `application/json` for that url?

Comment: @meder
Yes I've tried setting the Content-Type, same issue.

Comment: if you're not receiving a `Content-Type: application/json` reply from the webservice then even if it's replying a json object it will not work.

Comment: The response you get is really a valid JSON? Are you sure? Can you provide the output you get when you open the page manually?

Comment: When loaded manually I receive a incident.do file. When viewed in plain text its valid JSON; I can provide the output but its just JSON jargon in a .do file.

Comment: Is it cross domain? Are you making a request for a website outside from where you are? If it is, that is your problem. You will need a proxy.

Comment: No, it's not a cross domain call. See my edit for an example of what I'm calling.

Comment: When you call it, are you on `http` or `https`? That might be a problem. If you are on `https` try to use a relative path...

Comment: @imagineblue It could well be a cross domain domain call. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `contentType`

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authinfo);        
},
   url: "https://test.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",

   contentType: "application/json",

   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(a,b,c) {
     alert(a);
   }
 });
```

**UPDATE**

This is the correct way to call. But if you are making a request to a page out of your domain it will not work. For that you would need a proxy.
Here is a simple PHP proxy:

```
<?php
    /* Set the headers for application/json , xml, or whatever */
    echo @file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET['url']));
?>
```

Then your request would have to be to this page, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authinfo);        
},
   url: "myproxy.php?url=" + escape("https://test.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords"),

   contentType: "application/json",

   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(a,b,c) {
     alert(a);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) The problem was this: I was making these calls on the same domain as the server but the proxy my computer was using to connect to the domain was only setup for IE! It wasn't working in Firefox, but when trying the code in IE it worked fine, so it ended up being a proxy issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try removing `"type": "GET"`. jQuery Ajax requests are GET by default.</strike>

Perhaps you hitting browser XSS limitations. Is the web page served over HTTPS as well? If the page containing the ajax call is HTTP and the AJAX endpoint is HTTPS it would violate same origin policy. More discussion [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/a6123861a984a548?hide_quotes=no&pli=1).

From jQuery doco:

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   the same origin policy; the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules), http://test.com and https://test.com are different origins and hence violate same origin policy. Try making your page HTTPS as well.

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authinfo);        
},
   url: "https://test.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(a,b,c) {
     alert(a);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but after removing "type": "GET" I'm still having the same issue